# Slicing data frame for N steps in the future - tensorflow

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I'm currently tinkering with Tensorflow in my spare time.  I came up with a simple data set:

```
A   B   C   D   E
1   2   5   7   9
2   4   10  14  18
3   6   15  21  27
4   8   20  28  36
5   10  25  35  45
6   12  30  42  54
7   14  35  49  63
8   16  40  56  72
9   18  45  63  81
```

I am slicing the data as follows:

```
sc = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))
training_set = dataset_train.iloc[:,:].values
scaled_training_set = sc.fit_transform(training_set)
time_step=3
X_train = []
Y_train = []
for i in range (time_step,len(training_set)):
  X_train.append(scaled_training_set[i-time_step:i,:])
  Y_train.append(scaled_training_set[i:i+3,3])
X_train = np.array(X_train)
Y_train = np.array(Y_train)
X_train = np.reshape(X_train,(X_train.shape[0],X_train.shape[1],-1))
print(X_train.shape,Y_train.shape)
```

And my model is as follows:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(units=50,return_sequences=True, input_shape=(X_train.shape[1],X_train.shape[2])))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(LSTM(units=50,return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(LSTM(units=10,return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dense(units=3))
model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='mean_squared_error')
model.summary()
model.fit(X_train,Y_train,epochs=50,batch_size=time_step)
```

However, when I attempt this model, I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-120-ec3d3648bdb9> in <module>()
     13 model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='mean_squared_error')
     14 model.summary()
---> 15 model.fit(X_train,Y_train,epochs=50,batch_size=time_step)

13 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py in convert_to_eager_tensor(value, ctx, dtype)
     96       dtype = dtypes.as_dtype(dtype).as_datatype_enum
     97   ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 98   return ops.EagerTensor(value, ctx.device_name, dtype)
     99 
    100 

ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type numpy.ndarray).
```

I am assuming this is an issue with either (1) how I am slicing the dataframe or (2) how I am tinkering with the hyperparameters.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Edit:
To address the comment below, I padded Y_train[4] and Y_train[5] so as to make them be arrays with 3 elements.  This still throws the above error.

Comment: I think not all sequences have the same length when you append them to `X_train`

Comment: When I sliced this, I get (6,3,5) and (6,).  If I am not mistaken, this means it has broken up the data into slices of 3 time steps.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you are trying to do in the part where you slice the data? What are you trying to create as X_train and what is your Y_train? Will appreciate if you can explain using the dataset. example - `first 3 rows as X and next row as Y` or something like that

Comment: I would like the first three rows to predict the next three values of column A.  Columns B-E are "features".

Comment: You have lot of problems here. 1) Why is your output `Y_train` a part of your input `X_train`? 2) While trying to predict the next 3 values of column `D` during slicing the last two slices will have only 2 and 1 timestep values (unequal nested lists lead to jagged arrays) 3) Converting a numpy array to tensor needs to be done before feeding it to the model